# Dynamically populate google_tag_params on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, google-ads-api

I am using `google_tag_params` for Adwords. I am trying to set it after the page has loaded because the value I want is not introduced until an Ember component has rendered.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var topicCategory = '';
console.log("1");
var topicView =  require('discourse/views/topic').default;

 topicView.reopen({

      didInsertElement : function(){
        this._super();
        console.log("2");
        topicCategory = this._controller.model.category.name;
      }
});
$(function() {
    console.log("3");
    var google_tag_params = {
        category: topicCategory
    }
});
</script>
```

`google_tag_params` is not picked up in the above code, but the console.logs run correctly (1,2,3). I remove the document on ready, `google_tag_params` is recognized, but the console.logs run out of order (1,3,2).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the async google tags library that lets you fire a global function instead of relying on `onload`.

https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/asynchronous/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Usage looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
window.google_trackConversion({
  google_conversion_id: 123456789, 
  google_custom_params: {
    parameter1: 'abc123', 
    parameter2: 29.99
  },
  google_remarketing_only: true
});
//]]>
</script>
```